# Optimizing range queries in SPARQL in MarkLogic

Tags: sparql, marklogic

I want to write a SPARQL query that cross references an entity with a single time point with a set of entities that have time ranges.  Here's the graph pattern:

```
{
  ?entity :atTime  ?probe. 
  ?interval :startTime ?start ; 
            :endTime ?end . 

  FILTER (?start < ?probe) 
  FILTER (?probe < ?end)
}
```

One way for the query engine to run this is to find all the entities with `:atTime` defined, find all of the intervals, and perform all of these checks.  But MarkLogic (and most databases) have facilities for range indices, so that this can be done much more efficiently.

I have seen in the ML docs that you can use `cts:contains` in SPARQL to reach its string indices.  Is there a way to do something similar with range queries?

Some databases recognize design patterns in code like what I have quoted here, and they do that optimization themselves (which keeps the code standard!).  Perhaps MarkLogic does this?  I can't find any documentation telling me about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MarkLogic's triple index can perform range queries directly, so there's no need for a separate range index. The optimizer should recognize and optimize this query pattern.